# Embedding images in html in clojure postal not working for Gmail or macOS mail

Tags: html, clojure

I am sending an email using [postal](https://github.com/drewr/postal) with this body:

```
:body [
{:type "text/html;charset=utf-8;"
                :content "<div> <img src=\"cid:file.png\" alt=\"filename\" Your Order has been received\"> <div>"
                }
{:type :attachment
                :content (java.io.File. "/path/to/file.png")}
]
```

My goal is to have the attached file.png be loaded as an image in the html. However, even though the attachment is being sent, the image isn't being loaded in the html at least on gmail and macOS mail. For the cid, I tried both the complete path and just the file name, but neither worked. How do I fix this?

Comment: not sure how to do this with postal, but you need to explicitly set a content ID header:
`Content-ID: <file.png>` 
(note the angle brackets)

Comment: setting :content-id "<foo>" doesn't work. Are there other, better ways in clojure to send email with html that have images in them other than postal?

Comment: can you post the actual MIME content of your sample email? That way we can check what's missing in your output